# Advantage of using prototype over creating functions in the constructor?

Tags: javascript

Here's a constructor for an animal object.

```
function Animal(name, sound) {
   this.name = name;
   this.sound = sound;
   this.makeSound = function() {
       alert(sound);
   }
}
```

I have found that a developer can instead add an instance method to the Animal class via

```
Animal.prototype.makeSound = function() { alert(this.sound); };
```

and exclude the makeSound method from the constructor. What is the advantage of using this prototype design pattern?

Comment: How many function-objects are there for each new object in both cases?

Comment: I'm thinking many objects for both cases.

Comment: Only `function ()` creates a new function-object. So many function-objects are created in either case for: `animals = []; for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { animals.push(new Animal()) }` Also, modifying the `prototype` affects *all* objects that have in it their `[[prototype]]` chain.

Comment: Oh thank you, so all objects instantiated from a constructor reference the same prototype object by default via the `__proto__` property.

Comment: Well, the `TheConstructor.prototype` property. The `__proto__` property is an implementation detail exposed in some browsers (e.g. FF?); it would be nice if this was standard, but it is not. The `[[prototype]]` used is taken as the object `TheConstructor.prototype` property evaluates to at the time of `new TheConstructor` (one could technically change the `prototype` property between `new` calls, but I can't say I've seen this done...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The prototype version should only be created once and stored in memory, whereas the constructor version will create a new function in memory and store that with the object.

It's more of a memory management thing. Functionally, it's pretty much identical.

Answer (score 2):

A prototype "exists" for an instance of the object. When you create one of these objects, that data is optimized to already be there, instead of changing that object each time you instance it. ... And what Tejs just said.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover you have a public access to the original method (`Animal.prototype.makeSound`) that could be useful.